# Capture the [cdc]?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request, tag-disambiguation

I've stumbled across [cdc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cdc), with currently 496 questions. The [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cdc/info) explicitly refers to multiple unrelated things:

> CDC may refer to the Communication Device Class (or USB CDC). Also may refer to Change Data Capture in Microsoft SQL Server or PostgreSQL. Also may refer to Connected Device Configuration in Java ME. Also may refer to IBM Change Data Capture software, AKA IDR.

The mandatory points:

- Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

  It explicitly describes at least three distinct concepts (Communication Device Class, Change Data Capture, Connected Device Configuration)
- Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

  Yes, all three concepts may be on-topic.
- Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

  Maybe.
- Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

  No.

---

There is a tag [change-data-capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/change-data-capture) that might be a candidate for retagging some of the questions, and this one is also mentioned in some old discussions about potential alias relations.

Comment: Those three mentioned uses are programming-related enough IMO, as well as having enough questions and activity to keep. I'd say disambiguation would be preferable.

Comment: Disambiguation is definitely the better choice here. A block on CDC may then also be needed to ensure that it isn't created again.

Comment: I went with Center for Disease Control and Prevention.

Comment: Certainly Doesn't Contribute much to questions.

Comment: Well for those of us of a certain age it clearly refers to Control Data Corporation

Comment: How about removing change data capture from the [cdc] tag description? I'd try that straight after retagging existing posts.