# Is there more I should be doing about a user's useless comments, or are they actually "helpful"?

Tags: discussion, comments, english

Over the past few months, I've seen a specific user constantly posting what I can only describe as utterly useless comments. With comments that just consist of things like:

> CDDC CDDC CDDC

> CDC is Change Data Capture

> Buna No.

> Buna DIn nou. Please

There's also times where they will mix and match the nonsense with actual words; such as the last comment in today's screenshot (see later in the post), where they start off with nonsense text and then post partial code or English like this:

> Buna, DIn Nou. Just store values using HierarchyID type

Some of the comments are on *ancient* questions as well; the CDC comments I've seen on questions as old as *13 years*.

This is *not* a small amount, and it's been on going since *at least* December last year. For example, this is just *some* of [today's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wy731.png) (I've already flagged several today prior to this screenshot) and Saturday's ([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akfKJ.png), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPI96.png)).

I've been raising "No longer needed" on these comments, and have raised custom moderator flags, but they are *still* continuing to post the messages.

I've also tried engaging with the user: for the *"Buna DIn nou. Please"* comments I've both advised them of the "English Only" policy, and linked to the new help center article, and also asked them to explain, in English, how a user does a "Buna BIn nou". For the "CDC is Change Data Capture", I've advised that a better solution would be to them to add the tag [change-data-capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/change-data-capture) and (if applicable) remove [cdc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cdc), as it's not a helpful tag and that they might want to upvote [Capture the [cdc]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417294/capture-the-cdc). These comments keep still appearing.

Should I just continue flagging them as NLN, or should I be doing something else? Should I continue to try and engage even though it falls on deaf ears? I do not jest when I say I have probably raised far more than 100 or more flags on their comments since early December.

Comment: NB: Google says this could be romanian for "hello again". as for the gibberish... regardless of the user's intent, it's noise, wastes everyone's time. My experience with SO tells me that some things will not be dealt with, even when they should be dealt with.

Comment: Blargh, comments with "Hello again" and nothing else are still useless (it would make sense, as the user's profile suggests that is their nationality).

Comment: *"I've been raising "No longer needed" on these comments, and have raised custom moderator flags, but they are still continuing to post the messages."* - Flagging is not going to change the deeply rooted cultural background of a person. It is only going to get comments removed.

Comment: Have you raised custom moderator flags on comments or on a post. Custom moderator flags on comments don't really work very well, you need to flag a post. Any post will do.

Comment: @Gimby but flagging might prompt a mod to send an educational message to the user.

Comment: @Gimby "deeply rooted cultural background" sounds wrong. Unless the implication is that all people from that country/region would be commenting in this manner. It's a personal behavior.

Comment: *"Have you raised custom moderator flags on comments or on a post"* yes, @RobertLongson : "I've been raising "No longer needed" on these comments, *and have raised custom moderator flags*" I've done both.

Comment: Suspicious account to say the least... Unactive in the network since 2017 and suddenly comes back with a rather strange behaviour

Comment: @PhobosFerro: There is a market for Stack Overflow accounts. One symptom is a sudden *completely* different writing style.

Comment: I can only find one custom mod flag that you've raised about this, and it's still pending. We just haven't gotten around to handling it yet. Our lack of response doesn't mean that it's not an issue, or that you shouldn't have flagged it, or anything like that. Individual comment flags are *way* easier to handle than custom flags requiring extensive investigation, deciding what to do, writing a message to the user, etc. It'll get done eventually, though. (Even if it has to wait until you win your own moderator election! :-p)

Comment: @sweenish it is not always wrong though. You can't assume anything either way. Regardless, it is likely not going to change a personality either.

Comment: A couple of the flags have been custom mod flags on the comments, @CodyGray ; I've certainly raised *at least* 2 of those.

Comment: Ah, yeah, those aren't custom mod flags. Those are "I think this comment should be deleted, but one of the standard deletion/flag reasons doesn't apply, so I want to write my own explanation" flags. In other words, *all* comment flags mean one thing, and one thing only: delete this comment. They don't lead to any other follow-up action. If you want additional action to be taken above, beyond, or instead of deleting the comment, you need to raise a proper mod flag, which must be done on a post, not on a comment.

Comment: @CodyGray-onstrike " In other words, all comment flags mean one thing, and one thing only: delete this comment." - then why are the "harassment" and "unkind" reasons separated out? Aren't violations of the Code of Conduct supposed to merit penalty (or at least consideration for penalty) in comments the same way that they would in posts?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I'm intentionally going to ignore the specific context here and the nature of the comments themselves in order to write a generic, generally-useful answer.

**It depends on what you want to see happen.** In the style of the classic *Choose Your Own Adventure* series of books, your options are:

1. **Flag the comment(s) themselves** as "no longer needed" (or some custom reason, if more explanation for why they should be deleted is needed). Do this **if your intention is to get the comments removed** (i.e., deleted).

   Sometimes, the flag will result in the comment being immediately deleted by the system because it matches a "heuristic" (in this case, a relatively fancy word for a regex). Other times, the flag will need to be reviewed by a diamond moderator, who will decide either to delete the comment (thus marking the flag as "helpful") or keep the comment (thus marking the flag as "declined").
2. **If you think there's a larger pattern** that should be brought to someone's attention, then **raise an "in need of moderator intervention" flag on a post**.

   Use the textbox provided to write a detailed explanation of why you are raising the flag. Unfortunately, there is a character limit, so it cannot be as long as this Meta question. However, there is, generally, sufficient space for you to lay out your concerns (unlike the space given to us mods when handling the flag). In the case of comments, you do not need to include links to every post where you saw a comment, or even enough to establish a pattern, because moderators have access to a page that shows a user's full comment history. Noting the pattern of comments that we should look for is enough, along with, obviously, alerting us to the existence of a pattern worth looking for.

Basically, option #1 is how you play whack-a-mole with individual comments. *Normally*, that's enough. But when it's not, escalate to a custom moderator flag. These two options can be combined for maximum profit, although it's *probably* unnecessary to do them both at the same time. (If you've escalated to #2, this will result in the comments being deleted, so they don't need to be flagged individually at the same time. However, generally, you'll do option #1 for a while before deciding to switch to option #2, and that's totally fine/expected.)

Keep in mind that there are over 20 moderators on Stack Overflow, and some of us are <strike>[context-free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar)</strike> busy and forgetful, so you should not expect us to realize there's a pattern in your no-longer-needed comment flags. If there's a pattern we need to handle, then it needs to be brought to our attention specifically with a custom flag.

Sometimes, though, there's not really any need for a pattern to be brought to our attention. It's often easier and more efficient for everyone to just flag and have individual comments removed. Use your discretion, armed with the understanding you now have of how the system works and what the available options mean.

Also note that "engage with the user" is not one of the options I've listed.

Answer (score -18):

Don't make this too complex; just flag the comments if they're not useful.  No need to engage with the user or anything like that; a diamond mod can come along and do that if the user persists with their comments.

Comment: I would just like to note that there are like 20 mods and we might not notice a pattern from just NLN flags. So if there's a pattern, use a custom mod flag.